# Translation of "conscius" [sic] on stamp (Characters identified: 自覚的)

Tags: translation, character-identification

We got this stamp as a gift. What does the Chinese characters translate to? It seems too long to just translate to "conscius" [sic].

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`自觉的`, just "self-conscious".

Note that, `覚` is seldom used today. It's an interchangeable character for `觉`(simplified Chinese) or `覺`(traditional Chinese), which means *sense/feel*.

PS: I think the one who made the stamp maybe didn't know Chinese. He or She might search *conscius* in an electronic dictionary and found the Chinese meaning `自觉的`. However the translation can be greatly refined :)

Comment: Agreed, if it were me, I'll make it 自律.

Comment: Maybe they didn't know English either? Conscious is the usual spelling :)

Comment: @YuHao Doesn't 自律 mean "(self-)disciplined"?

Comment: @StumpyJoePete Yes it does. As the natural purpose for self-consciousness. To avoid being superfluous, assuming the stamp maker wants to say 'self-conscious', it should be 自觉 without 的.

Comment: @NS.X. I'm not sure what the _intended_ meaning of the stamp was, but if they were trying for the English word "conscious", then "self-disciplined" is probably not the intended implication.

Comment: @StumpyJoePete [*cōnscius*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/conscius) is Latin. And "conscius" is the name of their company.

Comment: This doesn't mean self-conscious at all, at least not in modern usage. Nowadays it means self-disciplined or without having to be told. Self-conscious, in English, means to be overly concerned about what other people think of you, which has nothing to do with 自觉 at all.

Comment: @deutschZuid: I was aware of this. In daily usage, no doubt, you're right. However, many English-Chinese dictionaries translate self-conscious to 自觉的 [***as a psychological or philosophical jargon***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-consciousness#Psychology) -- what you said is just *public self-consciousness*. As the stamp had translated cōnscius to 自觉的, I acquiescently considered it adopted the meaning "private self-consciousness", which can actually be translated to 自觉的.

Answer (score 2):

As the others have noted it means 'self-conscious.' The 的 adds a meaning of "being self-conscious" or "having the property of being self-conscious."

However, 觉 is simplified but 覺 is traditional.  This leads me to believe that the stamp was made from Japan/Japanese, since the same Chinese character when rendered in Japanese it looks like 覚.

自覚的

This expression has basically the same meaning for both Chinese users of traditional and simplified and Japanese.  (And probably Korean, though they would use 覺.)

Comment: Formally Japanese use [覺](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E8%A6%BA#Kanji) too.

Comment: well... traditional characters are still widely used today. In Chinese mainland, you can most of the Calligraphy are in traditional Chinese characters. And in Taiwan and Hongkong， they don't have simplified Chinese, they keep using traditional Chinese. However, in China mainland, simplified characters are offcial

Comment: Speaking of the traditional set, Hong Kong uses a traditional set *slightly* older than the one used in Taiwan.  You can see this in the use of: 為 (Taiwan) vs. 爲 (Hong Kong).  You can also see this in the use of 神 where in Hong Kong the left radical is rendered as 示 and in Taiwan the left radical looks like a ネ.  (I'm simulating these through a Japanese font...)

Comment: I mean "Japanese use 覺 as a formal character **too**". Yes, Japanese use 覚 more often. BTW, if you don't @me, I can't see your message :)